Excel formula needed for getting output for a particular series
First column/series is the input and second column is the required series/result/output. For example if the values in first column changes from 0,9,9,9 it will show 0,3,6,9 in second column. Another example, if the value in first column changes from 18,0,0,0, it will show 18,12,6,0 in second column. Another example, if the value in first column changes from 18,15,15,15, it will show 18,17,16,15 in second column.  Want to calculate second column based on the first column using excel formula. I can only go down or up by 3 in every step. Need excel formula for the same :


Is the second column in your image the desired output that should be generated by a formula? Is there anything you've tried yet? Can you include the data in Table Markdown (and add current state of data, whatever you tried and a desired output)

yes..second column is desired output...no solution from my end on this

Perhaps This somewhat similar question can help you get started?? Let us know if it is somewhat the same, and maybe someone can adapt it to your situation!

You state you want to only increase and decrease by 3[%], but when you go from 18% to 15% you show decrease by max of 1%.  Not critical to a solution, but you'll want to clarify to get an accurate answer.

My bad..Up or down in 3 steps..so when it goes frm 18 to 15..it goes down by 1 point each

Another SCAN Option:
=SCAN(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A30)),LAMBDA(Z,Y,AVERAGE(INDEX(A2:A30,MAX(Y-2,1)):INDEX(A2:A30,Y))))



=IFERROR(SCAN("",A2:A34,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(COUNTIF(A2:y,y)>3,y,x-(XLOOKUP(TRUE,A2:y<>y,A2:y,,,-1)-y)/3))),"")
This will create a blank for the first 3, since you wanted to do it in steps of 3 and they would all error.
